# Excel VBA program for HTML integration references login screen after logging in

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a website I am trying to integrate with using VBA through Excel.  I have the logging-in process down, but after the program logs in, it still references the login screen when, for example, I look for all "div" tag names.  This seems to be because the website does not load in the traditional sense; the address is the same regardless of what is clicked on, and if you run:

```
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
```

right after clicking the button to log in, it will hit 4 on the first iteration.

In a problem that seems to be related to this, actions performed well after logging in reference the HTML text of the login screen.  Here is my code:

```
Sub WebpageFiller()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "(website here)"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
'varUsername = InputBox("Username?")
'varPassword = InputBox("Password?")
varUsername = "(username)"
varPassword = "(password)"
Call ie.document.getElementById("txtUsername").setAttribute("value", varUsername)
Call ie.document.getElementById("txtPassword").setAttribute("value", varPassword)
Call ie.document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
ie.Refresh
Debug.Print ("refresh passed")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Set divElements = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div")
Do Until divElements(i).Title = "Collapse menu"
i = i + 1
Loop
divElements(i).Click

End Sub
```

The first section (through clicking "btnLogin") works just fine, but even when I wait for a few seconds, well longer than it takes the next page to load, the divElements loop will reference the HTML of the login page.  Also, the "ie.Refresh" command does not even work.  Somehow, it worked once, and when that worked, it refreshed the page, and everything else went smoothly.

I apologize if I have asked or formatted this in a confusing way.  This is my first post, and I'll try to be proactive in answering questions and editing things to make everything more clear.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the HTML after logging in:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine or request Chrome Frame -->
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <title>[Page title]</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<script src="js/loadPlugins.js?v=' + (new Date).getTime() + '" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<script src="js/main.js?v=' + (new Date).getTime() + '" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
    </script>
</head>


<body class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-content-white">
    <div id="ucHeader"
        path="MenuHeaderFooter"
        controlname="Header"
        loadasync="true">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div id="ucLeftMenu"
            path="MenuHeaderFooter"
            controlname="LeftMenu"
            loadasync="true"
            style="height: 0px;">
        </div>
        <div class="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="page-content">
                <div id="ucMainContent" style="margin-bottom: 0px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ucFooter"
        path="MenuHeaderFooter"
        controlname="Footer"
        loadasync="true">
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            storeSecurityProfile({
                methodName: 'GetSecurityLevelsOfCurrentUser'
                , viewField: 'SecurityViewText'
                , levelField: 'SecurityLevel'
            });

            var params = getQueryStringParameters();
            $.each(params, function (paramName, paramValue) {
                params[paramName.toLowerCase()] = paramValue;
            });
            var path = params.p;
            delete params.p;
            var controlName = params.uc;
            delete params.uc;
            var loadType = params.loadtype;
            delete params.loadtype;
            var title = replaceAll(params.title, '%20', ' ');

            var numLoaded = 0;

            $('#ucHeader').fetchSmartControl({
                onLoad: function () {
                    numLoaded++;
                    onLoad();
                }
            });
            $('#ucLeftMenu').fetchSmartControl({
                onLoad: function () {
                    numLoaded++;
                    onLoad();
                }
            });
            $('#ucFooter').fetchSmartControl({
                onLoad: function () {
                    numLoaded++;
                    onLoad();
                }
            });

            function onLoad() {
                if (numLoaded === 3) {
                    Layout.fixContentHeight();

                    if (path && controlName) {
                        // gkb 04/22/16 - only relevant if we're loading the menu dynamically and asynchronously
                        //if (typeof IsMenuLoaded === 'function') {
                        //    // check n times (with x interval) to see if dynamic menu is done loading
                        //    // -if menu loads within n attempts, try to load menu item for path/controlName passed in
                        //    // -if menu does not load within n attempts, or if path/controlName not found in loaded menu, load ucMainContent with path/controlName
                        //    var numAttempts = 0;
                        //    var maxAttempts = 5;
                        //    var interval = 500;
                        //    var menuLoaded;
                        //    TryLoadMenuItem();
                        //}
                        //else {
                        //    LoadMainContent();
                        //}
                        TryLoadMenuItem();

                        function TryLoadMenuItem() {
                            setTimeout(function () {

                                // gkb 04/22/16 - only relevant if we're loading the menu dynamically and asynchronously
                                //menuLoaded = IsMenuLoaded();
                                menuLoaded = true;
                                numAttempts++;

                                if (menuLoaded) {
                                    var pageLoaded = LoadMenuItem(path, controlName, {
                                        params: params
                                        , loadType: loadType
                                    });

                                    if (!pageLoaded) {
                                        LoadMainContent();
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (numAttempts < maxAttempts) {
                                    TryLoadMenuItem();
                                }
                                else {
                                    LoadMainContent();
                                }
                            }, interval);
                        }
                        function LoadMainContent() {
                            $('#ucMainContent').fetchSmartControl({
                                path: path
                                , controlName: controlName
                                , params: params
                                , loadType: loadType || 'Default'
                                , title: title
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And before logging in:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <title>
 [Title]
</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" /><meta name="description" /><meta name="author" /><meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<script src="js/loadPlugins.js?v=' + (new Date).getTime() + '" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<script src="js/main.js?v=' + (new Date).getTime() + '" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
    </script>
</head>

<body class="login">
    <div id="ucMainContent"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            $('#ucMainContent').fetchSmartControl({
                path: 'Home'
                , controlName: 'Login'
            });
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first "div" found with my code returns a blank title and "ucMainContent" id, so it is definitely looking at the login screen.

Comment: Are there any [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) tags in the HTML of the page? These are used to create an inline frame and could exhibit the behaviour of the webpage address not changing even after the login button is clicked

Comment: ^^ sharing html (using the snippet tool via [edit].. not as an image) would help answer that one

Comment: There are no iframe tags.  Here is the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

So I seem to have found the solution to this, and it is bizarre.  When I would log in to the website, a second version of IE would open up, as viewable in the Task Manager.  The "ie" variable would continue to reference the first (now invisible) instance, which seemed to remain on the login page, while the one shown in the web browser proceeded on to the next page.  I had to use the following code to switch between instances of IE to select the correct page:

```
Dim i As Variant
i = 0
Dim Get_IE_Window2 As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set Get_IE_Window2 = Nothing
Dim newIe As Object
Dim Shell As Object
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Debug.Print (Shell.Windows.Count)
While i < Shell.Windows.Count And Get_IE_Window2 Is Nothing
    Set newIe = Shell.Windows.Item(i)
    If Not newIe Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print newIe.LocationURL, newIe.LocationName
        If TypeName(newIe) = "IWebBrowser2" Then
            If TypeOf newIe Is SHDocVw.InternetExplorer And newIe.LocationURL <> "[login page url]" And InStr(newIe.LocationURL, "file://") <> 1 Then
                Set Get_IE_Window2 = newIe
            End If
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
Set ie = Get_IE_Window2
```

And I was wrong, the url did change when I logged in, but there was no loading behavior.  This allowed me to iterate through the programs to find the one that was not on this login page.

Let me know if there is anything I need to clarify in this answer.